# QGIS How to Load Symbology from PostGreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, symbology, style

I am slightly out of the loop and trying to catch-up with QGIS and Postgres.

1. Opened a new QGIS project.
2. Connected to PostgeSQL.
3. Added Layers.
4. Trying to add Symbology to each layer by…
   a. Double-click on layer
   b. Click on Symbology
   c. Click on Style
   d. Click on Load Style
   e. Click on relevant Style related to the layer
   f. Load Style
   g. Click Okay

Nothing happens!

I can see the 'Style related to the layer' in my options next time, but it is greyed out and I can't click on it.

[image: POI greyed out and can't select]

- Should I ask for the actual QGIS Project file instead and then re-connect with the aws server?

Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: What is in the Layer_Styles postgres table? https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360018377598-QGIS-Storing-Styles-in-Databases

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by asking for the original QGIS file, which had all the links and styles.